# python - findall and multiline combine results

Tags: python, regex, findall

I have two findall statements that work well separately. But I'd like to combine them into one statement.  How do I allow of continuous find not stopped by any /n?

Beautiful soup is not an option for bigger picture.

Code

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import re
import os

f = open(os.path.join("data.txt"), "r")
text = f.read()

print (text)

fValue = re.findall(r"line-height: 1.45;\"\>(.*)</h3><p class=3D", text, re.MULTILINE) #Value1
print ("fAdd: " , fValue)
fPrice = re.findall(r"(\$.*)</p>", text, re.MULTILINE) #price
print ("fPrice: " , fPrice)

fCombine = re.findall(r"(\$.*)</p>.*\n.*line-height: 1.45;\"\>(.*)</h3><p class=3D", text, re.MULTILINE) #price
print ("fCombine: " , fCombine)
```

Data

```
-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif; text-decoration: none; color: #323232; f=
ont-weight: 500; font-size: 16px; line-height: 1.38;">$144,900</p><h3 class=
=3D"highlight-title" style=3D"margin: 0; margin-bottom: 6px; font-family: '=
Montserrat', sans-serif; text-decoration: none; color: #323232; font-weight=
: 500; font-size: 13px; line-height: 1.45;">Value1</h3><p class=3D"hi=
ghlight-description" style=3D"margin: 0; font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-se=
rif; text-decoration: none; color: #323232; font-weight: 500; font-size: 13=
```

Results:

```
fValue:  ['Value1']
fPrice:  ['$144,900']
fCombine:  []
```

Desired:

```
fValue:  ['Value1']
fPrice:  ['$144,900']
fCombine:  ['Value1','$144,900']
```

Comment: You example string has 7 lines, each ending `"=\n"`. Is that intended? It's as though you are using `=` as a line continuation character (rather than `"\"`).

Comment: Yes, "=\n" thats correct.  Thats the sample data set. I'm just trying figure out how to do a continuation from each line until the next match is found.

Comment: Yes, "=\n" thats correct.  Thats the sample data set. I'm just trying figure out how to do a continuation from each line until the next match is found. How do I do a continuation from the first match to the second match which can be multiple lines later.  I'm essentially looking for what beautiful soup does with findall.

Comment: You do not need `re.M` anywhere in the patterns. Where you planned to match linebreaks with `.`, you need to use `re.S` or `re.DOTALL`. Or remove the flag and use `[\w\W]+` or `(?s:.+)` to match any text (lazy variants - `[\w\W]+?` or `(?s:.+?)`).

Comment: See [the demo](https://tio.run/##pZJdS8MwFIbv8ysOUdgq7dzsFG2bytDLiYLijVOobWoDaRLSiJt/fiZd/VyvHLnI18n7vk84amUqKcL1mtVKagOaImTo0gABjHFQZjXjqwgGV1KYhmqdmYEPTSaawO5YGYMrDgqaS3vFpIhASEFjyCWXOoK98MiNGEqCrELwRtlLZSI4Ho/tmTtp2DuNYHKiljFwJmhQdSWTUXga43R/Mp36Z@NxcqjSpAoh51nTEETCS1zZQu6KA8MMpxgas@LU3dSZfmE2izXZLINnaYysI2h9WuMvNIJ2hvtGI6gHLuyBmx5buPuMv9JJcliFaaI6tBaMoE@0gja5ZsrZ9wP@hulDIeifMH0oxLYFQmWb3DaJpqOSiSLjfKjxNuICL9Lh6ODc22L02zy@E7j1YG/zE0hpJgwMcTkriggw@LBx8lB5o1m@5Thc7D88JY8HnmuPn5qX13ez@dwKK/fsW7dV6ZTbtWdhLmT9bKP3iG@iq9TOO8D9ydDZdSm6nbdefwA).

Comment: Why is BS/lxml not an option? Regexes are not meant for HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Since your regex patterns are working as you want. An easy option would be to use the boolean OR operator to combine them.

The pattern would become:
`r'line-height: 1.45;\"\>(.*)</h3><p class=3D|(\$.*)</p>'`

using `findall` on this will return two match objects with two groups in them, but not all the groups will have values in them:

```
pattern = r"line-height: 1.45;\"\>(.*)</h3><p class=3D|(\$.*)</p>"
matches = re.findall(pattern, TEXT, re.MULTILINE)
print(matches)
# [('', '$144,900'), ('Value1', '')] the 1st tuple is the first match,
 which has only the price, the second tuple is the second match which doesnt have a value but has a price.
```

You can use `finditer` too, if you use capture groups the answer becomes a lot clearer but the result will be similar.

```
pattern = r"line-height: 1.45;\"\>(?P<value>.*)</h3><p class=3D|(?P<price>\$.*)</p>"
matches = re.finditer(pattern, TEXT, re.MULTILINE)
for match in matches:
    print(match.groupdict())

# {'value': None, 'price': '$144,900'}
# {'value': 'Value1', 'price': None}
```

regex test: https://regex101.com/r/yEISii/1

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Unfortunately, this adds additional data that I don't need in the result.  It complicates it, since this is a subset of a lot larger result set.  I'm essentially looking for a way take the "text" and match the pattern across multiple lines.  So the result is ['Value1','$144,900'] not {'value': None, 'price': '$144,900'} and {'value': 'Value1', 'price': None}

Comment: It's not an "|" statement. I"m looking for both in one

Comment: I'm essentially looking for what beautiful soup does with findall.